# How do I avoid Delphi interpreting special characters as parameters in SQL?

Tags: sql, delphi

I want to run a Sql query with special characters in it. However, I don't want to use sql parameters. There is a way to run following query?

```
SqlString := 'Select * from Table1 where Name LIKE '`1234567890-=\]['';/.,<>?:"{}|+_)(*&^%$#@!~%'
FSQLQuery.SQL.Clear;
FSQLQuery.SQL.Add( SqlString );
FSQLQuery.Open;
```

Delphi considers this query as Parameterised due to colon sign in 
'`1234567890-=]['';/.,<>?**:**"{}|+_)(*&^%$#@!~%' 
 and throws (No value for parameter '{}|+_)(*&^%$#@!~%').

Comment: The show code should not even compile, since the part behind Name LIKE ' is not part of the string. Colon within quotation marks should not be parsed as parameters, outside you could use ParamCheck=false

Comment: Maybe reading [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) will make you want using SQL parameters :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put something like this:

```
sqlString := 'SELECT * FROM   Table1 WHERE  Name LIKE ''`1234567890-=\]['''';/.,<>?:"{}|+_)(*&^%$#@!~%'' ';
FSQLQuery.ParamCheck := False; //<<It MUST be prior than SetSql.
FSQLQuery.SQL.Clear;
FSQLQuery.SQL.Add( sqlString );
FSQLQuery.Open;
```

Answer (score 1):

If `FSQLQuery` is `TADOQuery` then the easiest way to avoid this problem (colon char inside `SQL.Tex`) is to use 
`FSQLQuery.Connection.Execute(FSQLQuery.SQL.Text)` instead of `FSQLQuery.Open`. 
In this case you call ADO method directly without having Delphi parse your `Sql.Text`.

Answer (score 0):

Attention to escaped chars inside SQL too, it is possible to resolve with QuotedStr function to works fine:

```
sqlString := 'SELECT * FROM   Table1 WHERE  Name LIKE ' +
             QuotedStr('`1234567890-=\]['''';/.,<>?:"{}|+_)(*&^%$#@!~%'' ) + ';';
```