# How do I set a sql query parameter in Delphi that contains an '@'

Tags: sql, delphi, parameters, firebird

I am querying a database using an email address. The address is like fred.o'neill@smxi.com

In Delphi that looks like `fred.o''neill@smxi.com` as the apostrophe is escaped of course.

Let's say the query is...

```
'select * from table where (email = ''%s'')'
```

Now if I just replace %s the query fails as it seems to see the value as 2 strings 'fred.o' and 'neill@smxi.com', i.e. it doesn't recognise the escape.

If the query is...

```
'select * from table where email = :email'
```

...then the parameter is set to the email address. It works if there is no apostrophe but doesn't match the data if the email address contains one.

[edited to remove incorrect data]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Database is FireBird 2.5.2

Comment: What happens with an email address not having an apostrophe?  Something like a@b.com?

Comment: using an email without the apostrophe fails when using QuoteStr to set a parameter as it is looking for 'a@b.com' not a@b.com

Comment: So it runs without error?  Then the problem is not the @, it's the apostrophe.

Comment: Yes, without the apostrophe setting the param without quotestr works fine.

if it has the apostrophe it fails to match the data. 

I had been going around in so many circles the @ became a red herring, sorry

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17042344/how-do-i-avoid-delphi-interpreting-special-characters-as-parameters-in-sql?rq=1

Comment: @RBA have tried the QuoteStr and that doesn't work - see below

Comment: When using parameters, do not add the quotes or escape anything yourself.

Comment: @MarcusAdams still doesn't work. The address in the db is  fred.o'neill@smxi.com and passing that as a string (so when viewed in Delphi it looks like 'fred.o''neill@smxi.com' is accepted as a param but fails to match

Comment: @RussellWeetch, it did not make it into your database correctly then. Try `SELECT *` and take a look. This happens to me sometimes when I get it wrong at an earlier stage.

Comment: @MarcusAdams direct querying with select * from person where email = 'fred.o''neill@smxi.com' works (using FlameRobin)

Comment: @RussellWeetch, that's not even valid SQL. You must escape the apostrophe/single quote. What exactly are you typing?

Comment: that is valid, it is an escaped quote mark by duplicating the single quote see:http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/qsg10-firebird-sql.html

Comment: @RussellWeetch, sorry, if you didn't edit your comment, then my dyslexia got the better of me. I didn't see the extra quote. Yeah, maybe there's a bug then. Though, I think the server handles this.

Comment: a strange one this. and annoying a customer

Comment: What type of field? It's not any binary type is it, like blob? Only string fields are escaped.

Comment: Please add the exact code you are using. plus specify what Data components you are using and which provider?

Comment: Delphi XE2, FireDAC TADQuery, Firebird 2.5.2 with fbClient.dll - all fully updated - but see answer below. Thanks

Comment: In that case I suggest you delete this Q.

Answer (score 8):

When using parameters, do not add the quotes or escape anything yourself.

This should work:

```
var
   email: String;
begin
  email := 'fred.o''neill@smxi.com';
  MyQuery.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE email = :email';
  // Ensure that ParamCheck is enabled
  MyQuery.ParamCheck := True;
  // Explicitly set the type to string to ensure it's escaped
  // E.g. binary types are not escaped
  MyQuery.Params.ParamByName('email').DataType := ftString;
  MyQuery.Params.ParamByName('email').Value := email;
  MyQuery.Active := True;
end;
```

If it's not returning anything, check the actual values that are stored in the database. It may have not been escaped properly when it was inserted.

Comment: sorry, just tried hard coding the email address in but doesn't work

Comment: @RussellWeetch, I edited my answer and explicitly set the data type for the parameter. It's the only other thing I could think of.

Comment: +1. Just to be absolutely sure, I would add `ParamCheck := True` (True by default)